# Authenticate to Microsoft Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, microsoft-teams, azure-ad

Trying to connect to Microsoft Teams with app only azure AD authentication with the following command:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -ApplicationId GUID -CertificateThumbprint "thumbprint" -TenantId GUID
```

But getting error saying "The key does not exists".

Same thumprint works fine if i use it with `Connect-PnPOnline`. 
Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not with thumprint but Visual studio code. When i ran same script from Powershell ISE, so was every thing ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling modern authentication on Microsoft Teams Rooms (This May Work):

1. On Microsoft Teams Rooms, go to More (...).
2. Select Settings, and then enter the device administrator username and password.
3. Go to the Account tab, turn on Modern Authentication, and then select Save and exit.